# HDP3.1.4 - Spark2 with Hive Warehouse Connector error using spark-submit and pyspark shell: KeeperErrorCode = ConnectionLoss

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hive, apache-zookeeper, hdp

**Environment:**

- **HDP 3.1.4 -** configured and tested Hive server 2 - tested and working
- **Hive server 2 LLAP -** tested and working Spark configured as per documentation to use Hive Warehouse Connector (HWC)
- **Apache Zeppelin -** spark2 interpreter configured to use HWC

Trying to execute the following script:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark_llap import HiveWarehouseSession

# Create spark session
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("LLAP Test - CLI").enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()

# Create HWC session
hive = HiveWarehouseSession.session(spark).userPassword('hive','hive').build()

# Execute a query to read from Spark using HWC
hive.executeQuery("select * from wifi_table where partit='2019-12-02'").show(20)
```

**Problem:**
When submitting an application with spark-submit or using the pyspark shell with the above script (or any script that executes a query to with the HiveWarehouseSession) and the spark job gets stuck, throwing an exception: **java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: shadecurator.org.apache.curator.CuratorConnectionLossException: KeeperErrorCode = ConnectionLoss**

The command to execute is the following:

```
$ /usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/bin/spark-submit --master yarn --jars /usr/hdp/current/hive_warehouse_connector/hive-warehouse-connector-assembly-1.0.0.3.1.4.0-315.jar --py-files /usr/hdp/current/hive_warehouse_connector/pyspark_hwc-1.0.0.3.1.4.0-315.zip spark_compare_test.py
```

Here is the stacktrace:

```
[...]
20/01/03 12:39:55 INFO SparkContext: Starting job: showString at NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:0
20/01/03 12:39:56 INFO DAGScheduler: Got job 0 (showString at NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:0) with 1 output partitions
20/01/03 12:39:56 INFO DAGScheduler: Final stage: ResultStage 0 (showString at NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:0)
20/01/03 12:39:56 INFO DAGScheduler: Parents of final stage: List()
20/01/03 12:39:56 INFO DAGScheduler: Missing parents: List()
20/01/03 12:39:56 INFO DAGScheduler: Submitting ResultStage 0 (MapPartitionsRDD[3] at showString at NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:0), which has no missing parents
20/01/03 12:39:56 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_0 stored as values in memory (estimated size 9.5 KB, free 366.3 MB)
20/01/03 12:39:56 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_0_piece0 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 3.6 KB, free 366.3 MB)
20/01/03 12:39:56 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_0_piece0 in memory on EDGE01.machine:38050 (size: 3.6 KB, free: 366.3 MB)
20/01/03 12:39:56 INFO SparkContext: Created broadcast 0 from broadcast at DAGScheduler.scala:1039
20/01/03 12:39:56 INFO DAGScheduler: Submitting 1 missing tasks from ResultStage 0 (MapPartitionsRDD[3] at showString at NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:0) (first 15 tasks are for partitions Vector(0))
20/01/03 12:39:56 INFO YarnScheduler: Adding task set 0.0 with 1 tasks
20/01/03 12:39:56 WARN TaskSetManager: Stage 0 contains a task of very large size (465 KB). The maximum recommended task size is 100 KB.
20/01/03 12:39:56 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, DN02.machine, executor 2, partition 0, NODE_LOCAL, 476705 bytes)
20/01/03 12:39:56 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_0_piece0 in memory on DN02.machine:41521 (size: 3.6 KB, free: 366.3 MB)
20/01/03 12:42:08 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, DN02.machine, executor 2): java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: shadecurator.org.apache.curator.CuratorConnectionLossException: KeeperErrorCode = ConnectionLoss
    at com.hortonworks.spark.sql.hive.llap.HiveWarehouseDataReaderFactory.createDataReader(HiveWarehouseDataReaderFactory.java:66)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.DataSourceRDD.compute(DataSourceRDD.scala:42)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:109)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:345)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: shadecurator.org.apache.curator.CuratorConnectionLossException: KeeperErrorCode = ConnectionLoss
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.registry.impl.ZkRegistryBase.ensureInstancesCache(ZkRegistryBase.java:619)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.llap.registry.impl.LlapZookeeperRegistryImpl.getInstances(LlapZookeeperRegistryImpl.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.llap.registry.impl.LlapZookeeperRegistryImpl.getInstances(LlapZookeeperRegistryImpl.java:63)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.llap.registry.impl.LlapRegistryService.getInstances(LlapRegistryService.java:181)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.llap.registry.impl.LlapRegistryService.getInstances(LlapRegistryService.java:177)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.llap.LlapBaseInputFormat.getServiceInstanceForHost(LlapBaseInputFormat.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.llap.LlapBaseInputFormat.getServiceInstance(LlapBaseInputFormat.java:397)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.llap.LlapBaseInputFormat.getRecordReader(LlapBaseInputFormat.java:160)
    at com.hortonworks.spark.sql.hive.llap.HiveWarehouseDataReader.getRecordReader(HiveWarehouseDataReader.java:72)
    at com.hortonworks.spark.sql.hive.llap.HiveWarehouseDataReader.<init>(HiveWarehouseDataReader.java:50)
    at com.hortonworks.spark.sql.hive.llap.HiveWarehouseDataReaderFactory.getDataReader(HiveWarehouseDataReaderFactory.java:72)
    at com.hortonworks.spark.sql.hive.llap.HiveWarehouseDataReaderFactory.createDataReader(HiveWarehouseDataReaderFactory.java:64)
    ... 18 more
Caused by: shadecurator.org.apache.curator.CuratorConnectionLossException: KeeperErrorCode = ConnectionLoss
    at shadecurator.org.apache.curator.ConnectionState.checkTimeouts(ConnectionState.java:225)
    at shadecurator.org.apache.curator.ConnectionState.getZooKeeper(ConnectionState.java:94)
    at shadecurator.org.apache.curator.CuratorZookeeperClient.getZooKeeper(CuratorZookeeperClient.java:117)
    at shadecurator.org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl.getZooKeeper(CuratorFrameworkImpl.java:489)
    at shadecurator.org.apache.curator.framework.imps.ExistsBuilderImpl$2.call(ExistsBuilderImpl.java:199)
    at shadecurator.org.apache.curator.framework.imps.ExistsBuilderImpl$2.call(ExistsBuilderImpl.java:193)
    at shadecurator.org.apache.curator.RetryLoop.callWithRetry(RetryLoop.java:109)
    at shadecurator.org.apache.curator.framework.imps.ExistsBuilderImpl.pathInForeground(ExistsBuilderImpl.java:190)
    at shadecurator.org.apache.curator.framework.imps.ExistsBuilderImpl.forPath(ExistsBuilderImpl.java:175)
    at shadecurator.org.apache.curator.framework.imps.ExistsBuilderImpl.forPath(ExistsBuilderImpl.java:32)
    at shadecurator.org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl.createContainers(CuratorFrameworkImpl.java:194)
    at shadecurator.org.apache.curator.framework.EnsureContainers.internalEnsure(EnsureContainers.java:61)
    at shadecurator.org.apache.curator.framework.EnsureContainers.ensure(EnsureContainers.java:53)
    at shadecurator.org.apache.curator.framework.recipes.cache.PathChildrenCache.ensurePath(PathChildrenCache.java:576)
    at shadecurator.org.apache.curator.framework.recipes.cache.PathChildrenCache.rebuild(PathChildrenCache.java:326)
    at shadecurator.org.apache.curator.framework.recipes.cache.PathChildrenCache.start(PathChildrenCache.java:303)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.registry.impl.ZkRegistryBase.ensureInstancesCache(ZkRegistryBase.java:597)
    ... 29 more
[...]
```

I have tried the following with no effect whatsoever:

- Checked zookeeper health and connection limiting
- Changed zookeeper hosts
- Increased zookeeper timeout to 10s, 120s and 600s and no effect
- Tried to submit the application on multiple nodes, the error persists

There is another strange behavior, **running the script on the Zeppelin spark2 interpreter there is no error and the HWC works**. I have compared the environments, and there is no configuration mismatch on the main variables.

At this point I'm stuck and don't know where to look for further troubleshooting. I can add more information as requested.

Comment: Hello, any updates on this issue?

Comment: Hello, I have the exact same problem. HWC code runs in zeppelin but not with spark submit. Any updates?

Comment: Problem solved by setting --conf spark.hadoop.hive.zookeeper.quorum parameter in spark submit script.